# Alloy Array Model

Tags: testing, modeling, alloy

I just started learning alloy model language and was trying to write my own array model in Alloy. However, I was unable to extract index from a relation. Here is my sig and fact:

```
sig Element {}

one sig Array {
  // Map index to element
  IdxEle: Int -> Element,
  // Length of the array.
  length: Int
}

fact Index {
    all r : IdxEle | r.Int >= 0 and r.Int < length
}
```

The error I was getting was

```
This must be an integer expression.
Instead, it has the following possible type(s):
{none->none}
```

I looked over the reference guide but could not find a way to extract the idx field of the relation. Can somebody help me out?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, `r` in your model is of type `Array->Int->Element`, therefore `(Array->Int->Element).Int` cannot be computed since the last column in the tuple is of type Element, not Int as you seem to expect. (When you join in Alloy, the last column of the left side must be the same type of the first column of the right side.)

Second, there are easier, more flexible, and more readable ways to express what you want:

```
sig Element {}

let range[start,end] = {  i : Int | i >= start and i < end }

one sig Array { index : Int -> Element } {
    index.Element = range[ 0, len[this] ]
}

fun len[ array : Array ] : Int { # array.index }
```

Third ... there is a built in type for you called [`seq`](http://alloytools.org/quickguide/seq.html). It has everything you want and more.

Comment: Thanks so much, your answer really helped me getting a grasp of the data types and concepts of alloy. It also got me thinking whether I could implement that in one line of code (although that could sacrifice the flexibility and readability) So what I did was the following: 
`fact Index {
    all a : Array | a.IdxEle.Element >= 0 and a.IdxEle.Element < a.length
}`

However, when I execute that and show it, I got negative indices. What might be the cause of that? Thanks again.

Comment: It's because a.IdxEle.Element returns a set of Integers. I'm not sure how the `>=` operator behave when comparing sets but it seems from the results you get that not all the integers composing the set are compared.

Comment: A fix could be to check that the set of integer is contained in the integers succeeding `0` and preceding `Array.length`, respectively.  Putting the following Alloy formula in your Index Fact will solve your problem. 
`Array.IdxEle.Element in nexts[0] and   Array.IdxEle.Element in prevs[Array.length]` (I took the liberty of getting rid of the quantification as your Array signature has a multiplicity of one).

Comment: Thanks Loic, I went ahead to did some research on the nexts and prevs, those operations are really useful.

Comment: how to add elements in seq. For me s.add["sample string"] is not working